# Issue with fsolve - it returns complex roots

Tags: matlab

I am using the following code

```
x0=[2.01,3.20];
f = @(d) airy(1,-i^(1/3)*d(2))-d(1)*i^(1/3)*integral(@(n) airy(n),-i^(1/3)*d(2), 100);
fsolve(f,x0)
```

It returns a solution which is not the one I am looking for plus it is complex (fsolve should only return real roots!). Something is not working properly. Any idea?

Comment: Your function is complex valued so why wouldn't the roots also be complex? `i` is `1i`

Comment: Because according to section "Output Arguments" https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html?searchHighlight=fsolve&s_tid=doc_srchtitle the solution is real (no matter what you input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation online](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#buta__s-3) is a little unclear with respect to the output arguments. Since your input function is complex, it is going to have complex-valued roots as well. The documentation is likely referring to the fact that it ignores complex roots of a **real-valued** function.

For example, if we use the real-valued function `x.^3 + x.^2 + 1` instead of yours, we can see that despite that function having three roots (one real and two complex), `fsolve` only returns the real root

```
fsolve(@(x)x.^3 + x.^2 + 1, 1.5)
%   -1.4656
```

For your function, you can verify that the roots are indeed correct by substituting them back into your function and looking at the value of your function

```
R = fsolve(f, x0);
f(R)
%   1.5099e-13 + 1.4300e-13i
```

Comment: That's the thing, it should ignore possible complex roots, right? It does not!

Comment: @Hans Only if your input is real. Your input is complex

Comment: @Hans Please see the updated example which shows the difference in the behavior